# Help in Mapping?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, field-mapping

I'm trying to map the jira case fields with salesforce case fields 
but i'm stucked at mapping fields

```
         deserializejirajson.ResponseIssues theresult1 = (deserializejirajson.ResponseIssues)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),  deserializejirajson.ResponseIssues.class);
   System.debug('Results == :' + theresult1 ); 



      List<Case> casesToUpsert = new List<Case>();        
      for(deserializejirajson d : theresult1){

            Case c = new Case(); 
            c.Priority = d.Priority;
            c.Status = d.status;
            c.Subject = d.summary;
            c.Origin = d.issue_type;

            casesToUpsert.add(c);

    }
```

"here i get priority doesn't exist compile time error"

this is my deserialize class

```
global class deserializejirajson{

        public class ResponseIssues
        {

            public List<Issues> issues;

        }    

        public class Issues
        {
            public string expand;
            public string id;
            public string self;
            public string key;
            public Field fields;
        }    

        public class Field
        {
            public String summary   ;
            public Priority priority;    
            public Status status;
            public String Issue_type;        
        }   

        public class Priority
        {

            public String name;

        }    

        public class Status
        {

            public string name;

        }    

  }
```

Comment: ResponseIssues doesn't contain Priorities as a child, the deserializing class (which you might want to reformat the name to follow java class naming conventions) does. thresult1 is a ResponseIssue, so it doesn't have a Priority child. It is a grandchild.

Comment: @zgc7009 priority has one child I.e "name field"

Comment: Right, but ResponseIssues (d in your example) has a list of Issues, that contains a Field, that references a Priority. You can't just go directly from ResponseIssues to Priority without following the parent/child chain.